What does "cope with a nervous need" mean here?
In John le Carré's novel Smiley's people, I read:

Mostyn, no sooner settled, had flitted from the room to cope with a nervous need. They heard the thunder of the flush, loud as a brass band, and the gurgle of pipes all down the building.

Does that mean Mostyn needs to use the washroom instantly?

Yes, flush and pipes answers the question.

No, he nervously needs needs the toilet, not the washroom.

Nerves/anxiety cause some people to feel the need to urinate. So it may be nervous in that sense. I don't think it's a common euphemism but it's evident from the description what is meant.

@StuartF please change your comment into an answer and I'll mark it as the accepted answer

@Lambie Not simpler, but much more idiomatic: "a pressing need to pee" (https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=nervous+need+to+pee%2Cpressing+need+to+pee&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3) (zero "nervous need to pee", and it is not better for "urinate": https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=nervous+need+to+urinate%2Cpressing+need+to+urinate&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3)

@Lambie No, the result is not better in the way of confirming the idiomaticity of "nervous need" when it comes to using the bathroom.

@LPH "|No, the result is not better way in confirming etc." Who said result? Not me.

@Lambie I'm having a hard time following you now; it's "in the way", not "better way".

Have you ever had an urgent need to pee while in a situation where you can't leave (or there's no nearby toilet)? Did you fidget like you're really nervous while trying to hold it in?

That is what the author intends to say, but the use of the term "nervous need" might be questioned.
Out of the first thirty occurrences produced by Google Books (about 300 in total), setting aside the numerous false positives ("nominalized adjective-verb", punctuation between 'nervous' and 'need'", …), "nervous need" is a self defined combination in which both the need and the particular sense of "nervous" are to be apprehended on the psychological level (both specialized psychological literature and current language). This combination is therefore a massive collocation in the language. As found in the OP's sentence, the level, which is that of the human bodily functions, is physiological, and no such occurrence can be made out in that first section. A quick perusal of the remainder shows that this pattern  goes on unabated.
Moreover, the implication of nerves in  physiological processes is all pervading, which gives this "nervous need" the touch of a somewhat  over-defining term. As can be seen also from the examples, whether a nervous need is considered as a positive or a negative impulse, from the point of view of who is experiencing it, it involves always a positive outlook (nervous need to smoke, drink, eat, to be more productive, to get up, to prove oneslf, …), that of satisfying an urge towards self-gratification, which is not the case for that particular type of bodily function.
All the cases of the usual collocation in the first section are shown below without exception. In conclusion, it might be thought that this "physiological" "nervous need" does not show a careful use of language, and should perhaps be avoided.
(An Actor Prepares - Konstantin Stanislavsky · 1989) . He feels a nervous need to gratify the public, to show himself off and to hide his own state.
(Stay - Nicola Griffith · 2003) His body language—his excessive, almost cringing politeness, his careful button pressing, lack of swagger—was something I associated with his time spent in prison, where assertiveness is beaten out of you in a matter of weeks and replaced by a nervous need to plea(e.
(Free Review: A Monthly Magazine ... - Volume 2 - 1894) The pietism of Pascal is visibly that of an over-developed degenarating brain: that of Newman is visibly at bottom hysterical—the expression of a nervous need.
(The Forger of Marseille: A Novel - Linda Joy Myers · 2023) He welcomed the heat, a bone - deep intensity that bore down from the sky and heated the earth. He breathed it in, hoping the heat would calm his nervous need to do something, anything.
(Bach Flower Therapy and Homoeopathy for Psychic Illness - Page 318
Boedler Cornelia, ‎Cornelia Richardson-Boedler · 2003) The nervous need to move , if stifled , may precipitate such aggressive urges. The skin may express the psychological imbalance and trauma .
(Meet Cute - Jennifer L. Armentrout, ‎Katie Cotugno, ‎Nina LaCour · 2018) Now you're both laughing, too loud in the quiet house, harder than the moment deserves—giddy—both of you—with a nervous need to release crazy tension.
(Arius on Carillon Avenue: More than a Memoir: A Trinitarian Saga
Peter Carnley · 2023) At the very beginning of the assembly, apart of the nervous need to address “over-exposure to papists,” the threat of a perceived growth in antinomian- ism and the fear of social disorder that it might harbor bulked large as a prevailing concern on all sides.
(Proportionality in Crime Control and Criminal Justice
Emmanouil Billis, ‎Nandor Knust, ‎Jon Petter Rui · 2021)  makes way for a nervous need for ... quick fixes. In this way, criminal law is more and more frequently being used as a means to mark the different practices of life-styles with which we do not wish to identify ourselves
The Universe Within - Paramahamsa Prajnanananda
)
... on a chair, they tap their feet or always shake their legs in a nervous need for motion. Meditation enhances the ability to sit still in one UNIVERSE WITHIN position for an extended period of time.
(Confessions of a Viscount
Shirley Karr · 2021) In her experience, most men were in love with the sound of their own voice, or felt the nervous need to keep a dialogue going in mixed company even if the topics were inane.

Thank you for providing so much information and pointing out this term might not be good English, which is really enlightening.

The novel is by John le Carré, he is excused (pun intended)
